# How to have one static cell in a dynamic tableview?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I would like to use a `UITableView` to have 2 static cells on top of a list of dynamic cells. As far as I understand, I have to use a dynamic prototype tableView. But I don't understand how to add 2 static cells and design them, eg. adding a textfield to the first and a label to the second.

What do I have to do in my storyboard? And what do I have to do inside the Controller? How can I differentiate the static from the dynamic cells?

EDIT:
I tried this for testing:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 5
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CardTableViewCell
    
    //static cell
    if (indexPath.row < 2) {
        cell.dyn.text = "static \(indexPath.row)"
        return cell;
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.dyn.text = "buh"

    return cell
}
```

this results in this:

[image]

Later when I use real data I will miss the first 2 data rows...
Can I somehow "reset" the row counter after I created my static cells?

And how can I modify the 2 static cells? For adding a textfield and labels? Or do I have to do this programmatically?

Comment: i posted objective - C code but i hope you will get point how to start this.

Answer (score 20):

I found help here: [Mixing static and dynamic sections in a grouped table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607240/mixing-static-and-dynamic-sections-in-a-grouped-table-view?rq=1)

And my solution looks like this:

1.
[image]

2. Add and layout the static cells:
   [image]
3. Give each cell a unique name and add them as outlet to the `TableViewCell` class
4. Adjust the code:

   ```
   override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
       return 3
   }

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
       if (section == 2){ // my dynamic cell is index 2
           return 5 // just for testing, add here yourrealdata.count
       }
       return 1 // for static content return 1
   }

   override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

       var cell: CardTableViewCell!

       if (indexPath.section == 0) {
           cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static1", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CardTableViewCell

           cell.cardSetName?.text = self.cardSetObject["name"] as String

       }else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
           cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("static2", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CardTableViewCell // just return the cell without any changes to show whats designed in storyboard 

       }else if (indexPath.section == 2) {
           cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as CardTableViewCell
           cell.dyn.text = "row \(indexPath.row)" // return test rows as set in numberOfRowsInSection
       }

       return cell;
   }
   ```

End results will look like this:

[image]

I hope I can help someone with the same question :)

Comment: This approach is not working for me. Are you using a TableViewController or simply a tableView within a view?

Answer (score 4):

you could use something like this to use or display your static cell

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return numberOfDynamicCells + 1;
}
```

and in you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` datasource you may use something like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if(indexPath.row == 0){
// go ahead to display your static Cell
}
else{
//go ahead to display your dynamic cells.
}
return yourCell;
}
```

here is code for swift.

```
func numberOfRowsInSection(_ section: Int) -> Int{
return numberOfDynamicCells + 1
}
```

and in you `cellForRowAtIndexPath` datasource you may use something like this.

```
func cellForRowAtIndexPath(_ indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell?{
if indexPath.row = 0{
// go ahead to display your static Cell
}
else{
//go ahead to display your dynamic cells.
}
return yourCell;
}
```

Good Luck...

Comment: Your method works fine but there's still a trouble: if I change the height of the static cell, while running it become the same of the other dynamic cells; is there a way to set a different height?

Comment: same... there is a delegate of `UITableViewDelegate` as `heightForRowAtIndexPath` just make a check there too

Comment: oops that's right!! I didn't thought! Thank you again!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by having static cells be IBOutlet properties and in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` you can return those properties for any index paths you want

Here's an example:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  switch indexPath.row {
  case 0:
    return firstStaticCell
  case 1:
    return secondStaticCell
  default:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DynamicCell", for: indexPath)

    cell.textLabel?.text = "Dynamic \(indexPath.row + 1)"
    return cell
  }
}
```

[image]