# Swift - UITableView inside Cell from UITableViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uikit, tableview

I am trying to add a `TableView` inside my `UITableViewCellController` like this:

[image]

To add content to the cells i'm doing this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if (tableView == groupPicker) {
        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "")

        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(groups[indexPath.row]) - \(sets[indexPath.row]) Set\(ending(sets[indexPath.row]))"

        return cell
    }

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell\(indexPath.section)") as UITableViewCell

    return cell
}
```

groupPicker is my tableview inside the cell

I get this error:

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)**

on this line:

```
let cell = super.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
```

Is there another way to do this, or am I doing something from?

(All my cells are static, I need the table view inside the cell to be dynamic)

Thanks in advance

UPDATED CODE:

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (indexPath.section == 0) {
            var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "")
            cell.textLabel!.text = "Text"

            return cell
        }
        return tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell\(indexPath.section)") as UITableViewCell!
    }
```

I get this: (lldb)
Nothing else

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you don't need to allocate the cell. All you need is to dequeue cells from your tableView. Secondly, pass an empty string instead of nil in your cell identifier. Finally and it's recommendation, separate the implementation of your cells in two different cell types. The one that contains the tableView should conform on your TableView delegate and dataSource methods first.

Edit:

You can limit the editing in your tableView based on a specific section using this delegate method

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
       editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Comment: I've done the first two parts with no luck, as for the last part, I'm not sure what you mean. Could you give an example?

Comment: But firstly, why do you want to have a tableView inside another? Why don't you just section your table?

Comment: I need it for selecting a value to edit, and I need to be able to edit and move them around using the built in editing mode. I don't know how i can limit the moving to a single section, so I figured that this would be another solution.

Comment: Will I be able to keep my other static cells this way?

Comment: how will i edit the content of my cells in the first section while keeping the static cells then?

Comment: I updated my post showing the new code, I get a strange error

Comment: Your first solution is crashing due to super.tableView. It returns nil. And try `        tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(<#identifier: String#>, forIndexPath: <#NSIndexPath#>)`

Answer (score 0):

Does this maybe help?

[ios swift: How to have one static cell in a dynamic tableview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942400/ios-swift-how-to-have-one-static-cell-in-a-dynamic-tableview?noredirect=1#comment46139726_28942400)

I also think you need a unique identifier for each cell.

Comment: All my cells are static, i'm trying to add my tableview inside a static cell.

Comment: as far as I know, that is not possible, you need to have it as dynamic prototype table view, adding there extra cells for the static content. If you find out another way, please let me know!