# how to add image in a static cell of a table view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I have added an image view in one of the image view.I could have use Attributes inspector and then change the image property but i want to do it programmatically.

[image]

So far this is what i have done and get the following error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier account_cell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell:UITableViewCell! = UITableViewCell()


        if indexPath.section == 0{

            if indexPath.row == 0{
                cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("account_cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

                if let AccountImage = cell.viewWithTag(100) as? UIImageView{
                     AccountImage.image = UIImage(named: "Friend_g")?.imageWithRenderingMode(.AlwaysOriginal)
                }



            }
        }
        print("\(indexPath)")
        return cell
    }
```

Can someone give me a beginners guide how can i achieve it programmatically.Any help would be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Potentially duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751513/custom-uitableviewcell-register-class-in-swift

Comment: What is the name set of your cell in Inspector: "account_cell"?

Comment: @the_Ub you can see in the picture it is account_cell already.

Comment: Please see this for creating a [UITableViewCell in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27103278/creating-a-uitableviewcell-programmatically-in-swift) and this answer to [make your static cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28942400/ios-swift-how-to-have-one-static-cell-in-a-dynamic-tableview/28942718#28942718)

Comment: Can you share demo project? @jameshwartlopez

Comment: @Dharmesh here is the [demo project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwD5mmxKbcVpNDJ4ZFlqak1pNlU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `cellForRowAtIndexPath` for assign image in your cell because you cells are statics.

One easy way to assign image into static cell is just create `IBOutlet` of that `imageView` this way:

```
@IBOutlet weak var UserImage: UIImageView!
```

After that assign image to `UserImage` in your `viewDidLoad` method this way:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    UserImage.image = UIImage(named: "Friends_g")
    self.tableView.separatorColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

And result will be:

[image]

Comment: Happy to help you..:)

Comment: Can I ask how to center the image?

Comment: You can center it from storyBoard.

Comment: I use the Size inspector Arrange attribute to Center Horizontally in center but it doesnt center it.

Comment: So you want to center it with constraint?

Comment: Yes.  I also want to center it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100958/discussion-between-dharmesh-kheni-and-jameshwart-lopez).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It helps :D

Answer (score 0):

I am working with Objective-c and in Objective-c i can add image in cell using this following code.

```
UIImageView *imv = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,2, 20, 25)];
imv.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"user.jpg"];
[cell.contentView addSubview:imv];
```

Comment: can i use this on a static cell?And please your answer is objective c and not swift.