# How to have, in a grouped style, two contents : dynamic and static

Tags: swift, uitableview, cells

I know that there is this topic : "[Mixing static and dynamic sections in a grouped table view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17607240/mixing-static-and-dynamic-sections-in-a-grouped-table-view)"

But after many hours, I still don't have finished this litle "project" :

To do that :
[click there to see a screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juEhH.png)
(It's two grouped style : on the first group the cells are in a **dynamic** style and the other the cell is in a **static** style.)

So, I have a list :

```
var listOfWords = ["Cat", "Dog", "Horse", "Dolfin", "Robot"]
```

And I would display each word in each cell  -> so it is dynamic...

Then In the other group, down I would like to have a "cell-button" where if I click, I could create other word that would be added in the list.

So if someone can help me, it will be helpful !
(please send the code ;-) )

Comment: I am having a hard time figuring out the question.  Could you edit this post and provide a code sample along with the steps you have take to solve your problem so the community can better help you?

Comment: What is wrong with declaring the second section also as dynamic with a different prototype cell as a single item? It makes no difference for the appearance.

Comment: @vadian the problem is : how?

Comment: A table view with two sections and different prototype cells is very basic stuff. I guess there are millions of tutorials how to do that.

Comment: @vadian could you found one? please :)

Comment: Is the button *always* going to be on the bottom of the tableView?

Comment: @DustinPfannenstiel yes, the "button" for adding words in the list is a cell and it will be on the bottom...

Comment: Why not use a tableViewFooter?

Comment: @DustinPfannenstiel The problem is that I have a TabBarController => so I have tabs on th bottom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the button in a tableFooterView.

https://github.com/dpfannenstiel/symmetrical-octo-journey

Answer (score 1):

### Edited

You need to have two sections and manage them differently on the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` datasource method.

## First

Add two sections on the `numberOfSections` datasource method

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 2
}
```

## Second

Manage the `numberOfCell` datasource method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    switch section {

    case 0:
        return yourArray.count

    case 1:
        return 1

    default:
        return 0

    }

}
```

## Third

Manage each sections accordingly. Based on what you said, you want the first section to be dymanic and the second static.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section {

    // your dynamic cells
    case 0:
        let dynamicCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dynamicCell") != nil ? tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dynamicCell")! : UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "dynamicCell")
        dynamicCell.textLabel?.text = yourArray[indexPath.row]
        return dynamicCell

    // your static cell
    case 1:

        guard let staticCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "staticCell") else {
            let staticCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "staticCell")
            staticCell.textLabel?.text = "Static"
            return staticCell
        }

        staticCell.textLabel?.text = "Static"
        return staticCell

    default:
        return UITableViewCell()
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Also, there might some minor mistakes with my datasource methods name

Comment: `dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: for:)` returns never `nil` and strictly spoken any reused cell is not static.

Comment: Your **third** part don't works :(  Can you edit it please ?

Comment: Take a look at the edited answer, there were a few changes in other methods as well... Hope this helps

Comment: Hey Vadian, the `dequeueReusableCell` can return nil, but I wasn't using the right method. Just edited the answer. Take a look at apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614891-dequeuereusablecell